# SHTML and DHTML - Should they be used, why aren't they?

Tags: html, dhtml, shtml

With HTML 5 up, should we continue using the .dhtml and .shtml file formats?

Why does Js and CSS work even when we use HTML, without DHTML. Is this practice wrong?

Is there any advantage of SHTML over PHP?

If these 2 are not deprecated, why aren't they around?

Comment: Maybe HTML now has  both of their features?

Comment: I thought DHTML is HTML+JS+CSS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML

Comment: @EdHeal what bout the PHP vs SHTML thing. And the OP is asking why Js or CSS still work in HTML

Comment: @MrigankPawagi - PHP vs SHTML vs Java/Tomcat/Glassfish vs RoR doesn't matter - all server side implementation of parsing, some more flexible and capable than others, all as a "better" way to do CGI type stuff.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi - The Question _Why does Js and CSS work even when we use HTML, without DHTML. Is this practice wrong?_ Does not make any sense

Comment: @MrigankPawagi - Use of PHP/SSI or any other technology depends on what needs to be implemented, abilities of the programmer, ....

Comment: @EdHeal you should probably answer this question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## SHTML

There isn't any difference between using `.shtml` and `.php` files other than the languages in which they are parsed. `.shtml` contains `SSI` scripting, while `.php` contains `PHP` scripts. There isn't any specific reason to choose one over the other - it depends completely upon the developer.

## DHTML

`DHTML` isn't a different language or script from `HTML`. It just ***refers*** to the combined use of a markup language (`HTML`), a client-side scripting language (`JavaScript`) and a styling language (`CSS`). It simply notifies that your `HTML` page has dynamic content.

None of these are deprecated. It is just that `SHTML` has gone out of use as many people have switched to `PHP` and other server-side languages, and that people have minimized the usage of the term ***DHTML*** for talking about dynamic `HTML` pages, as now most of the websites have dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks! Got the meaning of the two now.